# Select an MD5 hash based on a combination of fixed strings and a column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

For the purpose of example, I have a table with a single column:

```
Col1 NVARCHAR(50)
```

It has a single row, and the value of Col1 is: `b`

I want to create a select statement that uses the value to create an MD5 hash, but the value needs to be appended to a couple of fixed strings in the format:

```
'a' + Col1 + 'c'
```

So effectively, I am trying to create an MD5 for `'abc'`, which should result in:

> 900150983CD24FB0D6963F7D28E17F72

To create the MD5 hash I am using the `HashBytes` function. However it doesn't produce the expected output when I join the fixed strings with the column value. For example:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', 'a' + Col1 + 'c'), 2)
```

results in:

> CE1473CF80C6B3FDA8E3DFC006ADC315

Which is wrong. However, the following all result in the correct output:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', 'abc'), 2)
CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', 'a' + 'b' + 'c')
```

Obviously it is something to do with using the field value, but I am lost as to what it is (maybe some encoding or something to do with it being nvarchar?).

What can I do to ensure the correct MD5 value is produced?

Comment: Try `BINARY(32)` instead of `VARCHAR(32)`. It looks like you're trying to convert an NVARCHAR to a VARCHAR. Also, what is `Col1`? You say it's `b`, but it looks to me like it could be something else.

Comment: try this select CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', 'a' + cast(@COL1 as VARCHAR) + 'c'),2)

Comment: @SoulTrain: Actually, casting to `VARCHAR` produced a completely different hash. But it works when you set a length/size for example: `VARCHAR(255)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column is `NVARCHAR` but the other values are all `VARCHAR`.

You can force your column to `VARCHAR`:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', 'a' + CAST(Col1 AS VARCHAR(50)) + 'c'), 2)
```

Comment: Thank you. I have been playing around with a few different functions on the field, including casting but with no luck. I even tried casting to `VARCHAR` (without a length). So I was pretty close!

Comment: You could also wrap the whole thing in a `cast`, if any part is of the `n` type, the rest of the concatenated values will be up-casted (not a word, but I'm sure you get my meaning!)